# How do I get a SINGLE value from my json? Angular 5/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

So I have a string[] variable and I want to only get the value of a specific key.

For example my string[] contains

```
{'firstname': 'john', 'lastname':'doe'}
```

In my view, I only want to display the last name. How do I do it?

```
{{myString.lastname}}
```

gives me blank.

```
{{myString}}
```

shows me

```
{'firstname': 'john', 'lastname':'doe'}
```

Comment: you said array? but you gave an Object. For Arrays, you need to specify the index as well. As for object, myString.lastname shiuld give you doe

Comment: I use string[] variable to store the json value I got from API. Not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Showing a piece of code where you get the value from wouldn’t be a bad idea either

Comment: Storing an object in a `string[]` is likely why you have this problem.  Try declaring it as `myString: any = {}`.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer- Please store API result in an Object. Public result: object=[ ];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to parse the string to a JSON object if it is just a string

```
let myObj = JSON.parse(myString);
```

Then you can call

```
myObj.lastname
```

Comment: If `myString` is actually a poorly named array, OP may need `myString[0]`

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. However, I'm not sure where would I put it into my code since I assign my value through observable. Any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer you can do .map((v) => JSON.parse(v)).sub.... before de subscribe

Comment: Hey @David i am having an nested JSON i want to access nested value any idea for that would help me .... :)